# Start on specific place on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I would like to know if there is a way to center a UIScrollview, if you will. Let me explain: I've made a ScrollView and connected it to some view controllers so that I can slide back forth, similar to as you would in snapchat. I have 3 view controllers. I wanted to know if there was a way that I could start off in the center view controller (Viewcontroller 2 or the "middle" view controller) instead of always starting on the very left. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can set the `contentOffset` of the scroll view to the origin of the "middle" view controller's view's frame.

Answer (score 0):

Set your scrollview's contentOffset.x value to a multiple of your viewController width (most likely the width of your screen).

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(yourViewControllerWidth, 0)
```

Where contentOffset.x = 0 is all the way to the left, setting it to the width of your viewcontroller will move the scrollview to the beginning of the next viewcontroller.

Comment: Using this method did work however I had to play with the width. I set it to the width (600) and it opened on the last view controller, I then cut it in half (300) to start on the view controller before it but it landed in between the 2nd and 3rd. The number that essentially worked was 206.5, but I don't think that'd a safe way to get it to open but it does technically get the job done.